# How to get a more informative crash log from GCP functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am using gcp functions, and I think the function crush log is not informative like below, which only mention `finished with status: 'crash'`.

Wondering how we can get a crush stack log to find out the bug easier?

Thank you.

```
{

insertId: "000000-e410caa4-0287-4e3f-b80d-c215e06a5430"

labels: {

execution_id: "pbc4oxnzl1ji"

}

logName: "projects/sturdy-hangar-2/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions"

receiveTimestamp: "2020-07-04T07:01:52.837476035Z"

resource: {

labels: {

function_name: "gen_thumbnail"

project_id: "sturdy-hangar-2"

region: "us-central1"

}

type: "cloud_function"

}

severity: "DEBUG"

textPayload: "Function execution took 91 ms, finished with status: 'crash'"

timestamp: "2020-07-04T07:01:51.834276757Z"

trace: "projects/sturdy-hangar-2/traces/1bbc73e71f5057d38ecb65be525b233b"

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that ambiguous crash logs without stack traces can be quite frustrating to troubleshoot and test. This is a known issue with Cloud Functions as of now and is actively being investigated by Cloud Functions specialists. I would suggest that you take a look at the [Public Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/155215191) and click the star icon to subscribe to the issue for further updates and click the bell icon to be notified of updates via email.

As all issues require a dedicated team of specialists to investigate them accordingly, we do not have an ETA on the resolution. Please rest assured that we are doing our best to get this issue resolved.